# Ajax executando Controller (MVC, PHP)

Tags: php, ajax, mvc, controller

começei a pouco dar uma estudada em mvc, e estou com uma dúvida. Como fazer com que meu ajax execute determinado método da minha controller.
Obs. Não estou usando nenhum framework, segue abaixo o código.

View

```
<div class="form-cadastro">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" required autofocus>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_usuario" placeholder="Nome de Usuário (Apelido)" onkeydown="Mask(this,user);" onkeypress="Mask(this,user);" onkeyup="Mask(this,user);" maxlength="20">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nascimento" placeholder="Data de Nascimento" onkeydown="Mask(this,DataM);" onkeypress="Mask(this,DataM);" onkeyup="Mask(this,DataM);" maxlength="10">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Senha" required>

    <div class="termos text-center">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-termos">Termos de Uso</a>
    </div>

    <div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="btn-cadastro">Aceitar os termos de uso e Cadastrar</div>

  </div>
```

js

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data:{
            nome: nome,
            username: username,
            nascimento: nascimento,
            email: email,
            senha: senha
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'controller/cadastro/index.php',
        success: function(msg){

            if(msg.erro == 0){

                window.location.href = "dashboard";

            }else{

                swal('Não foi possível cadastrar');
                fnLoading(false);
                return;

            }

        }

    })
```

controller

```
class cadastro{

    public function cadastrar(){

        $player = new Player();

        $player->nome       = mysql_escape_string($_POST['nome']);
        $player->username   = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $player->nascimento = mysql_escape_string($_POST['nascimento']);
        $player->email      = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $player->senha      = mysql_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

        $player->inserir();

    }

}
```

Comment: está acontecendo algum erro em específico?

Comment: Sem ser por Ajax você consegue acessar, digitando o endereço no browser?

Comment: O erro no console é: 404?

Comment: Sem framewok você provavelmente terá que criar um roteador, que recebe todas as requisições e passa pros arquivos correspondentes... Pode ser no index, você iria passar na url algo como: `controller/index.php?rota=cadastro` e no index chamaria a classe correspondente.

Answer (score 1):

O erro não estará no **url** no **ajax**?
 Você tem:

```
url: 'controller/cadastro/index.php'
```

Deverá ficar:

```
url: '_caminho_/cadastro/cadastrar'
```

Sendo que o link para chamar um **controller** segue o seguinte padrão:

```
Caminho/Controller/Method/
```

Sendo:

- `Caminho` : Corresponde ao caminho até ao controlador;
- `Controller`: Nome do controlador;
- `Method`: Método a utilizar dentro do controlador.

Mas se você quiser trabalhar com MVC, recomendo usar um framework, como [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) ou [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/).